# Form data always empty in ASP.NET MVC application inside subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdomain

I have two Asp.Net MVC Websites. The first one is inside the root domain *domain.com*, and the second one is a subdomain *sub.domain.com*.

Everything works fine inside the root domain, but I'm having trouble submitting a form to a controller on the subdomain. Whatever I try to send seems never to get to the controller.

It may seem strange but this problem does not happen when I try to start the application locally in debug mode. (locally is not a subdomain, just plain localhost).

Just for testing purposes I've build a simple model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string test_text { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the CSHTML partial view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TryModel", "Home", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    <input type="text" name="test_text" />
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
}
```

Even with this simple configuration, on my local copy I've no problem, but as soon as I start the application on the remote machine, the posted data is always empty.

What do you think could be the problem?

**EDIT**

This is the controller methods

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TryModel()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TryModel(TestModel model)
    {
        // code removed

        return View(model);
    }
```

And yes, the action is called correctly. Even the Request.Form is empty.

Comment: can you post your controller code? Also, just to be clear, have you verified that the controller method is getting hit on the remote machine and the posted data is null?

Comment: @G_P Added the informations you asked

Answer (score 0):

Html.BeginForm takes only 4 Parameter,

Parameters: **string actionName**, **string controllerName**, **FormMethod method**, **object htmlAttributes**

you should change the your parameter
from:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TryModel", "Home", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
```

to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TryModel", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
```

I hope it will helps.

Comment: It's the same, the empty new { } only specifies I dont' want query string params. The generated HTML is correct with "/Home/TryModel"